# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger - To catch insert with wrong name

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

So I am trying to write a Oracle Trigger that catches an insert into one of my tables where the value given is the wrong name for a foreign key in another table. So the trigger needs to change that value to the correct name, instead of the name that was given.

My database tables are setup like so:

```
SIGHTINGS (NAME, PERSON, LOCATION, SIGHTED)
FEATURES (LOCATION, CLASS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, MAP, ELEV)
FLOWERS (GENUS, SPECIES, COMNAME)
```

The tables have the following semantics:

- SIGHTINGS gives info that describes every time that a member of the club observes one of the wildflowers described in the table FLOWERS. NAME tells the name of the flower observed, PERSON describes who saw the flower, LOCATION tells the name of a nearby geographical feature where the flower was seen, and SIGHTED tells the day when the flower was seen.
- FLOWERS lists all of the flowers that the members of the club try to find. GENUS and SPECIES give the scientific name for the flower, and COMNAME gives the non-scientific name (SIGHTING.NAME is a foreign key into FLOWER.COMNAME)

I am trying to set up a trigger that catches inserts into the SIGHTINGS table, when a user accidentally inserts the Scientific name of the flower instead of its common name. For example, they might use:

```
INSERT INTO SIGHTINGS VALUES
  ('Chaenactis douglasii', 'Person A', 'Shirley Peak', TO_DATE('18-Aug-06', 'DD-MON-YY'));
```

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO SIGHTINGS VALUES 
  ('Douglas dustymaiden', 'Person A', 'Shirley Peak', TO_DATE('18-Aug-06', 'DD-MON-YY'));
```

I want the trigger to catch this problem, and print a warning message to the screen and then insert the common name into the database, rather the Latin name.

My code looks like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Used_Latin_Name
BEFORE INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.NAME IS NOT NULL)
DECLARE
    -- local variables
    inserted_name    VARCHAR2(30);
    comm_name        VARCHAR2(30);
    Invalid_name     EXCEPTION;
    Valid_name       EXCEPTION;
    -- local cursor
    CURSOR c (name_in VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT COMNAME
        FROM FLOWERS
        WHERE COMNAME = name_in;

BEGIN
    -- open cursor and fetch a match
    OPEN c(:NEW.NAME);
    FETCH c INTO inserted_name;
    CLOSE c;

   -- Raise an exception when foreign key is invalid
   IF inserted_name IS NULL THEN
       RAISE Invalid_name;
   ELSE
       RAISE Valid_name;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN Invalid_name THEN
        CREATE INDEX genusindex on FLOWERS(GENUS)
            indextype is ctxsys.ctxrule;
        SELECT COMNAME FROM FLOWERS
        INTO comm_name
        WHERE matches(GENUS, :NEW.NAME) > 0;
        DROP INDEX genusindex;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Warning: Your insert into the SIGHTINGS table seemed to use the Latin name "' || :NEW.NAME || '" for the flower "' || comm_name  '". I used the common name instead.');
   WHEN Valid_name
        NULL;
END;
/
```

I get an error though that you can not create an index where I am creating an index, so I was wondering if there is another way to do this other than the way I am doing it, or if there somewhere else I am suppose to insert the index. I have searches everywhere for help with this and have had no luck figuring it out.

Comment: Please only tag your question with the database you're actually using.

Comment: First, you can't create an index in a trigger.  Second, you wouldn't want to.  Creating an index, particularly an Oracle Text index, is a slow operation.  It would make no sense to create the index just to drop it moments later.  Third, do you really need an Oracle Text index to do the lookup you want rather than just having a standard index and doing a straight equality check?  Fourth, if you really have a foreign key constraint, that is likely to be violated before your trigger fires.  Fifth, this is probably not the sort of thing that should be done in a trigger, it belongs in the app.

Comment: There are more issues in your solution - if`SELECT COMNAME FROM FLOWERS INTO comm_name WHERE matches(GENUS, :NEW.NAME) > 0;` returns more than one row, you will get an error. Another issue - `DBMS_OUTPUT` is typically used for debugging, not for printing messages to the user. If you use it in the production code, you will get `ORA-20000 DBMS buffer overlow` sooner or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I figured out a solution to what I was trying to do and the code looks like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Used_Latin_Name
BEFORE INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.NAME IS NOT NULL)
DECLARE
    -- local variables
    inserted_name   VARCHAR2(30);
    comm_name       VARCHAR2(30);
    Invalid_name    EXCEPTION;
    Valid_name      EXCEPTION;
    -- local cursor
    CURSOR c (name_in VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT COMNAME
        FROM FLOWERS
        WHERE COMNAME = name_in;
BEGIN
    -- open cursor and fetch a match
    OPEN c(:NEW.NAME);
    FETCH c INTO inserted_name;
    CLOSE c;


    -- Raise an exception when foreign key is invalid
    IF inserted_name IS NULL THEN
        RAISE Invalid_name;
    ELSE
        RAISE Valid_name;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN Invalid_name THEN
        SELECT COMNAME 
        INTO comm_name
        FROM FLOWERS
        WHERE GENUS = SUBSTR (:NEW.NAME, 1, INSTR(:NEW.NAME, ' ') - 1);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Warning: Your insert into the SIGHTINGS table     seemed to use the Latin name ''' || :NEW.NAME || ''' for the flower ''' || comm_name || '''. I used the common name instead.');
        :NEW.NAME := comm_name;
    WHEN Valid_name THEN
        NULL;
END;
/
```

I used substr and instr to detect the first white space, and then find the correct entry with that substring that is formed.